# Trying to change a lightbulb out of a ceiling fixture

Tags: light-fixture

I am trying to change the light-bulbs in my kitchen ceiling light, I'm just unsure how to do it with this one without accidentally tearing it out of the ceiling.

Does anyone know how to unfasten this fixture, as well as what make it is?

[image: ceilinglight1]

[image: ceilinglight2]

[image: ceilingight3]

[image: ceilinglight4]

Comment: What does the horizontal screw in the third picture do?  Are there more like that?  That’s where I would start.

Comment: Fantastic pictures!! This is a prize winning example of how a new contributor posts a question with great supporting information and is able to get an answer in short order.

Comment: Please [take the tour](https://diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you know how to resolve this post.

Answer (score 4):

See that dimple in the third photo? I' guessing that there are three or four of them. They engage with slots in the other half of the housing.

Rotate the lower portion counter-clockwise roughly as far as the dimple is long and it should come down. You may have to align the screws on top with their slots as well. Loosen the set screw to avoid scratches.